# Doctrine 2 How to do a Sum from a Join but Group by 2 columns

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using Symfony and Doctrine Querybuilder to return a list of Orders with a count of all Products in each Order. That means I have a 1:n Relationship between Orders and OrderProducts the OrderProducts table stores the OrderID, and the quantity of each product. If I do a groupBy o.orderId then I get the correct Sum, but then I do not get the data for all the orderProducts belonging to the orderId so if there are 2 different Products in the orderproducts table then I get qty:2 but only the data for 1 product, so I need to group by oi.orderProductId but obviously as soon I add the second groupBy oi.orderProductId then the TotalCount is showing me the sum for each individual record. I am fully aware that this is the correct behaviour, but I just can not get my head around it if there is a way to achieve what I am trying to do. I assume I have to somehow use a subselect, but I am not sure if this is even possible to achieve. My 2 tables and my attemped so far

**tbl order**

orderId

dateCreated

**tblorderProducts**

orderProductid

orderId

qty

```
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->select(array(
            'o AS orderData',
            'oi',
            'sum(oi.qty)AS noOfItems'))
        ->join('o.orderItems', 'oi')
        ->groupBy('o.orderId')
        ->groupBy('oi.orderProductId')
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

I hope somebody can give me a hint how I could achieve it. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `groupBy()` method always replaces the current group by clause. Use `addGroupBy()` [method instead](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.10/reference/query-builder.html#group-by-and-having-clause).